# Secure Angular Routing

Tags: angular

When I select a user to edit it details, I am redirected to the URL http://localhost:4200/user/1/edit-user. My concern is If I replace 1 with any other number (eg.5), it fetches the details for user with Id 5. How can I make sure no other user details can be fetched by changing the id in url.

Thanks..

Comment: It's actually a big question about authorization. both front-end and back-end should do some works on it, and you can google some terms such as 'JWT,' 'web token,' 'cookie,' and 'session.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security concern, thats not angular-alone (or front-end-alone) concern. Server side involvement is required for such scenarios. Having said that, you have got a couple of options

1.) Encrypt all the route-values / query-strings that you doubt front-end user can edit / change.

2.) Call a service / function that passes route values to a server-side service and decide whether to allow access to a given component or not on each component constructor / ngOnInit. This is a tiring work.

Angular has a nice feature of **[RouteGuards](https://codeburst.io/understanding-angular-guards-347b452e1892)** that are interfaces which when implemented allow / deny access to a given route. In summary, a route-guard would get the **route** parameter and then implement some logic (shall mostly involve server-side) and return either true / false. In case a false value is returned, access to given route is denied.

Thanks.